# Multicolumn cells are not equal

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

I have tried this piece of code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{No.} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Initial concentration(M)} & \multirow{2}{*}{\Delta t_1} & \multirow{2}{*}{\Delta t_2} & \multirow{2}{*}{\Delta t_3} & \multirow{2}{*}{\Delta t_{ave}} \\ \cline{2-3}
    & \ch{Na2S2O3} & \ch{H2SO4} & & & & \\ \hline
    
    %%%%%Row 1%%%%%%%%%%
    1 & & & & & & \\ \hline 
    
    %%%%%Row 2%%%%%%%%%%
    2 & & & & & & \\ \hline 
    
    %%%%%Row 3%%%%%%%%%%
    3 & & & & & & \\ \hline 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This is what I got:[image]

Clearly, you can see that H2SO4 cell is wider than Na2S2O3 so how can I make those cells equal?

Comment: Did you try replacing specifiers for columns 2 and 3 with fixed width centred columns?

Comment: @Bernard No, I'm not. However, I will give it a try. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want (a) columns 2 and 3 to have equal widths and (b) the combined width of columns 2 and 3 to be just large enough to contain the string `Initial concentration ($M$)`, I suggest you proceed as in the first table shown below. The code first measures the width of the string `Initial concentration ($M$)` and then calculates the usable widths of columns 2 and 3 from this information. The approach employs the `w` column type, which is provided by the `array` package.

I would like to encourage you, though, to consider employing a different layout altogether, one with a more open and inviting "look". This may be done in a straightforward manner by getting rid  of all vertical lines and using fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal lines with the help the macros of the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) package. While you're at it, you could also provide more structure to the headers for columns 4 to 7 and assure that they have equal widths. See the second table for an implementation of these ideas.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mhchem,multirow,calc,array,amsmath,booktabs}
\newlength\mylenA
\newlength\mylenB
\newlength\mylenC

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[th]
% determine target width of combined cols 2 and 3:
\settowidth\mylenA{Initial concentration ($M$)} 
% determine usable width of cols 2 and 3:
\setlength\mylenB{(\mylenA-2\tabcolsep)/2}

    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| c | *{2}{wc{\mylenB}|} c | c | c | c |}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{No.} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Initial concentration ($M$)} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{$\Delta t_1$} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{$\Delta t_2$} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{$\Delta t_3$} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{$\Delta t_{\mathrm{ave}}$} \\ 
    \cline{2-3}
    & \ce{Na2S2O3} & \ce{H2SO4} & & & & \\ \hline
    1 & & & & & & \\ \hline 
    2 & & & & & & \\ \hline 
    3 & & & & & & \\ \hline 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

%% same table, but with well-spaced horizontal rules and no vertical rules:
\begin{table}[h]
% determine target usable width of combined cols 2 and 3:
\settowidth\mylenA{Initial concentration ($M$)} 
% determine usable width of cols 2 and 3:
\setlength\mylenB{(\mylenA-2\tabcolsep)/2}
% set target width of cols 4 thru 7:
\settowidth\mylenC{avg.}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{2}{wc{\mylenB}} *{4}{wc{\mylenC}} @{}}
    \toprule
    No. & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Initial concentration ($M$)} & 
    \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{$\Delta t$} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-7}
    & \ce{Na2S2O3} & \ce{H2SO4} & 1 & 2 & 3 & avg. \\ \midrule
    1 & & & & & & \\ \addlinespace
    2 & & & & & & \\ \addlinespace
    3 & & & & & & \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\settowidth` should go inside the `table` environment. For sure not in the preamble, where `\normalfont` has not yet been issued. And maybe the `tabular` requires `\small`… Or, maybe, one wants to change the header text…

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for these suggestions. I've updated my answer accodingly.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me.